# Output Weird Characters To Screen in PHP

Tags: php, character, symbols

I am trying to output to the screen strings that contain odd characters such as `® ™`. When I do so, `�` replaces all the odd characters. I have tried looking into `htmlentities()` but that did not output any of the odd characters. I know that I can use the HTML code, but that will not work in my case.

Comment: This looks like you're outputting ISO-8859-1 characters in a UTF-8 context, but it needs more info. Where does the string come from?

Comment: This string is coming from a form in my CMS (CQ5).

Comment: Do you output to terminal? If, yes which terminal program? Linux? putty?

Comment: That's still not enough info. Where are you outputting the data? In what context? Consider showing some code.

Comment: Right now I am testing with just a local variable: `var_dump( htmlentities('foo ®®', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump( htmlentities('foo ®®', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") );
```

Make sure your source file is UTF-8 encoded.

Most IDEs offer a "character set" option in the "Save As" dialog or somewhere in the file's options.

Answer (score 2):

You're entering the domain of character encoding. It confuses many people so here are some guidelines:

Since you're dealing with HTML you can *always* use `htmlentities`. This will give you something like; `&abc;` or `&#1234;`. These characters will always display correctly.

Another approach is to use characterset encoding. This means you have to make sure all your characters are output in the same character encoding and you give the correct character encoding hints to the browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

To force a browser to use UTF-8. You can substitute for ISO-8859-1 is that is your preferred encoding.

Then, if you all your input is UTF-8 your output should also be UTF-8. If it's not, convert it. `utf8_encode` will convert a string to UTF-8.

Comment: I have the `meta` tag in my website. I have tried `var_dump( htmlentities('foo ®®') );` but that renders `string(0) ""` to the screen.

Comment: That's very strange, it shouldn't do that. What is the character encoding of your source file?

Comment: UTF-8. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` is what I have in my header.

Comment: I tried `var_dump( htmlentities('foo ®®', ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8') );` but that rendered `string(10) "foo ��"`.

Comment: try saving your php file with the following encode:  UTF-8 Without BOM
you can do that by using notepad++

Comment: @shnisaka Originally, this value is being read in by the CMS which is done by the function `$config->title`. I don't have access to this function (located in another file) so I'm not sure if changing the encoding in my current file will have an effect.